# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

Ao executar este codigo aparece um erro, alguem poderia me ajudar? não consigo achar o erro no codigo abaicho.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Iniciando o App
const app = express();

// Iniciando o DB
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

// Primeira rota
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3001);
```

> **ERRO**

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
    at Function.listen (/var/www/html/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/NodeJS/server.js:18:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3001
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Se não estou enganado, esse erro quer dizer que algo esta usando sua porta `3001`, pode ser que vc esteja rodando esse script pela 2 vez e não "matou" o que vc rodou antes.

Comment: Poderia tentar outra porta? Por exemplo: `app.listen(3003)` ou `app.listen(3010)` e falar o resultado?

Comment: agora aparece essa mensagem :`(node:18136) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ouve esse erro:

```
(node:18136) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring
  engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use
  the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option 
  { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

Apos as mudanças no código como `app.listen(3001)` para `app.listen(3003)` e

```
mongoose.connect('mondodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

para

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

neste erro achei a solução neste poust [Server Discovery And Monitoring engine is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899638/12763394), 
que é basicamente, acresentar mais um termos :

> `useNewUrlParser: true`, `useUnifiedTopology: true`

Dentro da chaves: `mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi', {});`

Answer (score -2):

O erro ocorre porque a porta já está em uso.

Verifique a porta em uso com o comando abaixo:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:3000
```

Você receberá algo como isso.

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    22256 normal   18u  IPv6 117611      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Para resolver isso: feche a porta com o comando abaixo indicando o 'PID':

```
$ kill -9 22256
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).